# Whay do my divs move down on the page when there they have text in them and how can I fix this?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have noticed that when I have text in my inline-block divs they move down instead of staying in place how can I fix this so that is stays in line with the others with text inside?

Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Web site</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="jumbotron">

        </div>
        <center>
            <div class="listbox">
                <h1>exapmle</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="listbox">
            </div>
        <div class="listbox"></div>
        </center>
       <!-- container end div -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#container{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #669999;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.listbox{
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px; 
    background-color: #003333;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:5px;
}
#jumbotron{
    margin:2px auto 5px auto;
    background-color:black;
    border-radius:5px;
    height:450px;
    width:900px;
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening, because browser is trying match the *baseline* of all *inline* elements.

Add `vertical-align: middle` to `.listbox`

Answer (score 2):

Apply `vertical-align:top;` to your `.listbox` CSS class. This issue is due to default `vertical-align` value (`baseline`) , so when there is text, it affects baseline for all inline elements and pushes one with text down.

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RfJzU/)

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the `<h1>` tag you are having here:-

```
<div class="listbox">
    <h1>exapmle</h1>
</div>
```

You haven't specified any rule for it. Try adding this to your CSS:-

```
h1 { float: left; }
```